# After adding controller in active admin resource , validations error cannot be shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activeadmin

Previously i have form and show method in active admin resource. At that time validation errors shown in forms. But now i have to write controller in resource , after adding no more validation errors. Am i doing something wrong. Below is my code.

```
ActiveAdmin.register PsychographicsQuestion do

  config.clear_action_items!
  permit_params :id , :title,:psychographics_question_type ,:expiry_date , :_destroy , psychographics_options_attributes: [:id,:title , :_destroy]

  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs "Question" do   
      f.input :title , label: "Question"
      f.input :psychographics_question_type, label: "Question Type" ,:prompt => 'Select Answer Type', :as => :select, :collection => DemographicsQuestion.demographics_question_types.keys.to_a
      f.input :expiry_date, as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { min_date: 0}
    end
    f.has_many :psychographics_options,heading: 'Options' do |item|
      item.input :title 
    end
    f.actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :title
      row :psychographics_question_type
      row :expiry_date
    end
  end
  controller do
    def create
      question = PsychographicsQuestion.create(permitted_params["psychographics_question"])

      if question.id != nil

        PsychographicsQuestionFilter.create(@@filters)
        filter_user = User.search(@@users)

        for u in filter_user.result
          FiltersMatching.create(:user_id => u.id, :psychographics_filters_id => @@filters.to_i , :psychographics_question_id => question.id)
            #send_msg_through_gcm(u.to_i,"New PsychoGraphics question has been added.")
            NotificationsDatum.create(:user_id => u.id , :msg => "New PsychoGraphics question has been added." , :category => NotificationsDatum.categories["PsychographicsQuestion"] , :status=>NotificationsDatum.statuses["Active"] , :viewed_status=>NotificationsDatum.viewed_statuses["NotViewed"] , :psychographics_question_id => question.id)
          end

          redirect_to admin_psychographics_question_path(:id => 93)
        else
          redirect_to new_admin_psychographics_question_path(:id => question.id)
        end
      end
    end

    filter :expiry_date
    filter :created_at
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you just added blank create action in controller,

```
controller do
  def create
     create! { |success, failure|
     success.html do
       redirect_to admin_customers_path, :notice => "Resource created successfully."
     end
     failure.html do
       flash[:error] = "Error(s) : #{resource.errors.full_messages.join(',')}"
       redirect_to :back 
     end
   }
 end
end
```

Just remove blank `create` action or write it's implementation. Should work.

Comment: You are right , but i have to write business logic in create method. I have updated controller method in question. How can i accommodate above into controller create method.

Comment: You need to catch exceptions in `PsychographicsQuestion.create` and need to set `flash[:error]` accordingly

Comment: First of all, the errors are being displayed as a flash message and secondly it's redirecting the user back to the same page which clears all the fields. We would have to put in extra effort to fill the fields with the already filled data. I reposted this question and luckily found the answer by digging into activeadmin.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42462758/226783). It's the solution that is actually used by activeadmin.