# How to display errors in activeadmin forms after overriding controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a situation where I need to override create in activeadmin. I autofill the fields and if the data already exists it should update otherwise create. Here is my create method:

```
def create
      id = params[:company].dig(:id)
      if id.present?
        @company = Company.find(id)
        if @company.update(permitted_params[:company])
          redirect_to resource_url
          flash[:notice] = 'Company created successfully'
        else
          #add errors to semantic errors
        end
      else
        new_permitted_params = permitted_params[:company].except(:id)
        @company = Company.new(new_permitted_params)
        @company.save
        if @company.errors.any?
          #add this to semantic errors so that activeadmin handles and displays the errors
        end
     end
  end
```

I want to display the errors which violate the validations so that the user knows if he/she has entered an invalid entry.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965870/after-adding-controller-in-active-admin-resource-validations-error-cannot-be-s/37966168) but it looks like a workaround more than a solution. Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a new HTML file in views named `new.html.arb` and added `insert_tag renderer_for(:new)` in it. After that all I did was

```
if @company.errors.any?
  render 'new'
end
```

I discovered it by seeing the default behavior of activeadmin. I hope this helps other people who are looking to do something similar. This is the result that I get and which was required by me.

[image: Fields with validation errors.]

Comment: you may need to set `@resource = @company` before calling `render :new`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if client side logic to submit to different URLs depending on id.present? might make things more restful.

Comment: Let me explain you a lil why I did this. I have applied auto complete on this form and I'm setting all the fields with the data that I'm receiving. So that's where the logic comes into play. If ID is set (which wouldn't be if the I didn't select an object on auto complete), then update otherwise create.